# n-dimensional integral of radial function

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ only depends on the distance to $x$, $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f(\sum_i x_i^2)$. I want to know the volume integral of $f$ over the region $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_i\ge 0, i=1,\ldots,n,\sum_ix_i^2\le R\}$. The n-dimensional version of the region in the plane bounded by a circle at the origin of radius R, and the coordinate axes in the first quadrant. Is there a n-dimensional version of polar coodinates I can use to compute this integral, maybe in terms of the volume of the ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and in terms the integral of $f$ as a function of the radius $\sum x_i^2$?

Comment: Your condition does not mean anything, if the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$, then how can you take $f(\sum_i x_i^2)$ when it is a real ?

Comment: @AlexandreSallinen Is your issue that the formal argument to $f$ is the radius (which in turn has domain $R^n$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you have $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = g(r)$, where $r = \sqrt{\sum x_i^2}$ and $g:\Bbb R_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is an integrable function.

Then the integral $\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x_1, \dots, x_n)dx_1\dots dx_n$ can be evaluated as $\int_0^\infty g(r) \cdot  S_{n - 1}r^{n - 1} dr$, where $S_{n - 1}$ is the [volumn of the $(n - 1)$-dimensional unit sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area).

The value of $S_{n - 1}$ is discussed in the above wiki page. The simplest closed form is $S_{n - 1} = \frac{2\pi^{\frac n 2}}{\Gamma(\frac n 2)}$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the $r^{n-1}$ is the n-dimensional analogue of the $r$ in polar coordinates? How is the fact that the region of integration is restricted to just one octant reflected in the final formula? Wouldn't you expect some fraction of the unit sphere to show up, no?

Comment: If you only integrate over $\{(x_i)_i: x_i \geq 0 \}$, then just divide what I wrote above by $2^n$. This should be clear from symmetry.